# IUIAutomation not declared in this scope. & undefined reference to `CLSID_CUIAutomation'. MinGW64 uiautomationcore.h is wrong?

Tags: c++, mingw-w64, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm currently developing a screen reader project using C++. The problem starts when i tried to create an IUIAutomation object instance. The vscode and the g++ complains that IUIAutomation is undefined, even though the #include <uiautomation.h> works perfectly. After some digging into the libraries i discovered that the definitions of IUIAutomation are indeed missing from the uiautomationcore.h file (maybe to old versions?). MinGW64 update did nothing...

I tried "stealing" the uiautomation.h, uiautomationcore.h, uiautomationclient.h and uiautomationcoreapi.h files from the latest Windows SDK (under ..\Include\10.0.22621.0\um folder) and replace the old MinGW64 ones. This worked up well until there was the need to initialize the IUIAutomation instance.

According to [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-creatingcuiautomation), the code below should do the trick but it produces the following errors on compilation.

```
bool IUIARecorder::InitializeUIAutomation(IUIAutomation **automation) {
    if (!SUCCEEDED(CoInitialize(NULL))) {
        std::cout << "Error while CoInitialize()..." << std::endl;
    }
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUIAutomation, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&automation));
    return (SUCCEEDED(hr));
}
```

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccL19ouT.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.CLSID_CUIAutomation[.refptr.CLSID_CUIAutomation]+0x0): undefined reference to `CLSID_CUIAutomation' C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccL19ouT.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.IID_IUIAutomation[.refptr.IID_IUIAutomation]+0x0): undefined reference to` IID_IUIAutomation'

Seems that 'CLSID_CUIAutomation' & 'IID_IUIAutomation' are undefined, which is not the case if you see the source (from Windows SDK) in uiautomationcore.h.

For the sake of completeness, i need to integrate it with a Gtkmm inteface so i am kind off stuck with MinGW64. In the best of my knowledge i cannot use Msvc for the job.

Does anyone knows anything that can be helpful?

Comment: You could perfectly develop Windows-specific stuff in a lib using Microsoft tooling, including the official Windows SDK (this is *much* easier for Windows development), and use that from MinGW. Anyway, do you have a full reproducing file / project?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes you're right and thank you for your fast response :). I could definitely do that and might do it as we speak. Anyway, let's explore the issue first. Here is the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_glNSyv7DLMhaUoRsPLIdZBDKfb7rmHM/view?usp=share_link) that reproduce the error. As you can see, i tried creating custom instances of CLSID's and pass them into the function, which did compile but on runtime failed to initialize the object. (That's all done with the Windows SDK libraries copied into the MinGW64 include directory).

Comment: Your string to GUID code is wrong, it should be like this: `CLSIDFromString(L"{ff48dba4-60ef-4201-aa87-54103eef594e}", &CUIAuto);`. One other solution is to define the guids like this w/o code execution (can be put in header): `#include <initguid.h> DEFINE_GUID(IID_IUIAutomation, 0x30cbe57d,0xd9d0,0x452a,0xab,0x13,0x7a,0xc5,0xac,0x48,0x25,0xee); DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_CUIAutomation, 0xff48dba4,0x60ef,0x4201,0xaa,0x87,0x54,0x10,0x3e,0xef,0x59,0x4e);`

Comment: @SimonMourier Both solutions you provided did compile as normal but only the first one initialized the object correctly. Moving on on my implementation, just realized that there are more things missing such as 'undefined reference to `__imp_SysStringLen''. Seems that there is nothing much we can do (probably need more headers from Windows SDK?) except use the Microsoft tools to develop a lib an then use it in MinGW as you originally suggested. Thank you very much anyway :)